# Different Microsoft Edge image?

Tags: microsoft-edge

This may be irrelevant to Superuser, but I'm pretty sure MS Edge's logo looked like this:

[image]

But, now it looks like this:

[image]

Is there something I should be worried about? This only happens when I use the Cortana search bar.

Comment: Can you change it back in Properties, Change Icon?  The lower image looks like the original Edge icon.

Comment: @John Could you give me any direction on how to do that? When I right click on it, it only shows "pin to start", "pin to taskbar", and "app settings" which doesn't have anything to do with its properties.

Comment: Right click, select MORE...   and then Open File location. In the file location, you can right click on it, select Properties and change icon is there. I just did this. I also have Edge as a desktop icon and I can select properties there.